# Identify different regions in HR diagram

Tags: astrophysics

I'm given the HR diagram seen below and I need to identify the different regions.
I know them all except for the one circled which I have no idea what it is...
Can anybody help me out with this? Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The stars within the circle are "blue stragglers." They inhabit the blue end of the original main sequence, and should have left the main sequence long ago, but for some reason remain. Various theories exist as to their origin/longevity, but none are yet conclusive.

Comment: Another question, if I may, regarding the diagram. How can I determine the age of the cluster based on the given diagram?

Comment: The position of the main sequence turnoff point should determine the age. More accurate ways exist, but if you can find a chart of main sequence lifetime vs B-V, you can get a rough estimate.

Comment: Can I say that the main sequence mass at the turnoff point gives the current age of the cluster? This is why I believe there's an arrow right about the turnoff point.

Comment: Yes, that's precisely it, since there's a color-mass relation on the main sequence, the color of the turnoff point gives you the mass of a star, which gives you a lifetime on the main sequence for that star.

Comment: I would like to ask you a couple more questions, if I may, but I don't want to go off-topic here. Can we open up a chat?

Comment: @FlyGuy It will do so automatically when the thread gets too long, and I don't know a way to nicely do it otherwise.

Comment: It's showing it now but it says I don't have enough reputation to chat. I'll just ask away here then.

Comment: I'm asked if helium white dwarfs can be found in such a cluster and I think the answer is no since stars of such masses don't grow sufficiently massive helium cores. Am I correct with this?

Comment: @FlyGuy High-mass stars ($8-10.5 M_{Sun}$) give you ONeMg white dwarfs, while lower-mass stars give you CO white dwarfs. Helium white dwarfs cannot form from a single star, but rather get their helium from mass loss in close binary systems. Based on this, there is some chance of helium white dwarfs being in the cluster.

Comment: @FlyGuy I should qualify "helium white dwarfs cannot form from a single star" with the following: very low-mass stars ($<0.5 M_{Sun}$) cannot burn helium, so they would, on paper, create helium white dwarfs. The issue is that these stars have tremendously long lifetimes, in the hundreds of billions to trillions of years, so none of these stars should have died yet.

Comment: But the star that is pointed at with an arrow above is given to be  of a single solar mass, So it falls into the category, I believe, of CO white dwarfs (according to what you said). How can we then expect helium white dwarfs  in the cluster shown above?